# “This is my first visit of the USA”

Tags: prepositions

I have the sentence

> This is my first visit of the USA.

Is it correct?

How can I ask a person about this information? I think the following:

> Is it your first visit of the USA?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

The correct wording is "This is my first visit TO the USA", or "Is this your first visit to the USA?"

If you are going somewhere, you make a "visit to" that place.

A "visit of" means that the object is visiting you. That is, if you said, "This is the first visit of Uncle Joe", you would mean that Uncle Joe is visiting someone.

Comment: I wouldn't use "of" even if Uncle Joe was visiting. I'd say, "This was the first visit from Uncle Joe," or, "This was the first visit by Uncle Joe," or, "This was uncle Joe's first visit."

Comment: @J.R. Agree. My intention was to say, "If you said this, this is how it would be construed", and not "If this is the idea you want to convey, this is the best way to say it." On re-reading I see that my post was not at all clear on that point.